# sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input

Tags: python, sqlite

This is the error I keep getting for the `INSERT INTO` commands.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/cabca/.PyCharmCE2019.2/config/scratches/test.py", line 34, in <module>
    part43, part44, part45, part46, part47, part48, part49, part50))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

The code is trying to call a string in the second half, but that is not be possible. I know I can't remove the (), because that give it way more than the max of 2 it will accept.

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO _part_table_ (part1, part2, part3, part4, part5, part6, part7, part8, part9, part10,"
        "part11, part12, part13, part14, part15, part16, part17, part18, part19, part20, part21, part22, part23,"
        "part24, part25, part26, part27, part28, part29, part30, part31, part32, part33, part34, part35, part36,"
        "part37, part38, part39, part40, part41, part42, part43, part44, part45, part46, part47,part48, part49,"
        "part50)" (part1, part2, part3, part4, part5, part6, part7, part8, part9, part10, part11, part12, part13, part14,
        part15, part16, part17, part18, part19, part20, part21, part22, part23, part24, part25, part26, part27, part28,
        part29, part30, part31, part32, part33, part34, part35, part36, part37, part38, part39, part40, part41, part42,
        part43, part44, part45, part46, part47, part48, part49, part50))
```

Comment: Please submit a **minimal** example of your issue.

Comment: Just by trying to come up with a minimal example, you may solve your own problem

Comment: Updated, with new error. Fixed the original error.

Comment: The syntax in your updated question is wrong. You forgot a `,` between `"part50)" (part1` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `INSERT` statements are wrong. The form you are looking for is `INSERT INTO <table_name> (column1, column2, ...) VALUES(?, ?, ...)`. For example:

```
cursor.execute(
    '''
    INSERT INTO _part_table_ (
      part1,
      part2,
      part3
    ) VALUES (?,?,?)
    ''', 
    (part1, part2, part3))
```

P.S. The snippet you posted also has a syntax error: there should be a comma between `"part50)"` and `(part1`.

Comment: i believe that fixed the problem. All i have is a syntax error now. I'll try to figure it out before asking